# Biological modeling languages - some basic issues

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics, language

I am trying to get used to with couple of modeling languages in biological context like SBML, BioPAX, Kappa and BEL. Some basic issues came up to my mind that are unclear to me even after a lot of related studies I read.

1. Are there any causal reasoning algorithms available for SBML? If yes please give me the reference.
2. Which "framework" supports modeling and mining (e.g. candidate mechanism identification / identification of upstream controllers) in Kappa?

Anyone has any idea about these?

Thanks in advance!